# Technical stoppage, which visa required?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, australia

I am travelling to Brisbane (Australia) via Hong Kong from India. My flight from Delhi to Hong Kong is a direct flight but from Hong Kong to Brisbane is not direct. It is having a technical stoppage at Cairns (Australia) before it reaches Brisbane.

What kind of visa would I require? Am I supposed to have a single entry tourist visa or multiple entry tourist visa or either of those two along with a transit visa as it is having a technical stoppage in Cairns before I de-board at Brisbane.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have a valid visa to enter Australia, it works just as well if you enter Australia at Cairns as it does at Brisbane.

On a technical stop you may or may not leave the aircraft, and you may or may not be required to clear immigration. Whether you do or do not makes no difference to the visa you require. There are two possibilities:

1. You are required to clear immigration at Cairns. The flight from Cairns to Brisbane will be considered a domestic one, and you won't need to clear immigration in Brisbane.
2. You don't clear immigration at Cairns. You will then clear immigration at Brisbane.

In either case you clear immigration once. **A single-entry visa will work just fine.**

Make sure your visa will be valid at the date and time you touch down in Cairns.

Comment: If I am asked to de board the flight at cairns due to technical stoppage, and go for immigration which will use up the single entry visa at cairns. and after that when I am going for immigration at Brisbane, then would there be any issue as I am coming from India to Brisbane and my visa is already used up or stamped before the destination(Brisbane)

Comment: IF they push you through immigration at Cairns, then you *should* be treated as a domestic flight at Brisbane and not need to pass immigration again.

Comment: As I remember, CNS-BNE is outside Australian immigration. You will land at  BNE as an international passenger.